# Select current row and all previous rows from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's take an example: I have a table named mytab with the following fields:

```
Name   Age
-----------
Jack    19
Josh    26
David   23
```

What I need to do is to select all the rows of this table and for every row, to select all its previous rows, so the output should be:

```
Name   Age
-----------
Jack    19
Jack    19
Josh    26
Jack    19
Josh    26
David   23
```

So the query result contains the first row, then first and second rows, then first, second and third rows.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your data doesn't have an obvious ordering, so there is no "first" row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no first row in a table because they represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column that specifies the ordering.

Your is really weird -- it can produce lots of rows (`n * (n + 1) / 2` where `n` is the size of the table).

But you can enumerate the rows and self-join:

```
with tn as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by <ordering column>) as seqnum
      from t
     t
select tprev.name, tprev.age
from tn join
     tn tprev
     on tprev.seqnum <= t.seqnum
order by tn.seqnum, tprev.seqnum;
```

Answer (score 1):

A fun way of doing this which may perform better than self joining on a row numbered column is below [db <> fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6f462ad4e1758b79a59b03ab8df4b952)

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <ordering column> DESC) AS Weight
FROM #YourTable yt1
)
SELECT Id, Name
FROM T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID) - Weight AS RN FROM STRING_SPLIT(SPACE(Weight - 1), ' ')) CA
ORDER BY RN,  <ordering column>
```